# How to get a decomposition(factorization) from sum of decompositions of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Suppose I have a symmetric matrix $S$ (unknown) to be computed, which is represented by:
$$ S = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} A^{i\top}A^{i} = I + A^{\top}A + A^{2\top}A^{2} + \cdots, $$
where powers of $A$ (known) would decay to 0.

Now I want a decomposition of $S$, such that:
$$S = R^{\top}R.$$

Since $S$ is unknown, how can I get this decomposition $R^{\top}R$? Is there any relationship between $R$ and $A$, thus I don't need to compute $S$ to decompose $S$.

Comment: The decomposition is not unique. Even if you specify some unique decomposition, I don't think there is any nice explicit formula for $R$. Anyway, if $\rho(A)<1$, the series is guaranteed to converge to the unique solution of $A^TSA=S-I$. Perhaps this can help.

Comment: If $A$ is real and normal, then $S=(I-A^TA)^{-1}$ which is easy to calculate.

Comment: @greg  I think you have made a mistake. $(I-A^{\top}A)^{-1} = I + A^{\top}A + (A^{\top}A)^{2}+ \cdots, $ which is not equal to $S$. Since $A^{k\top}A^{k} \neq (A^{\top}A)^{k}$.

Comment: Yes, but if $A$ is real and _**normal**_  then $AA^T=A^TA$.

Comment: @greg, got it, but we cannot assume that $A$ is normal...

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on a comment by user1551, we have a relationship 
$$S-A^TSA = I$$
which admits a closed-form solution for $S$.
$$\eqalign{
 (I\otimes I - A^T\otimes A^T)\,{\rm vec}(S) = {\rm vec}(I) \cr
 {\rm vec}(S) = (I\otimes I - A^T\otimes A^T)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(I) \cr
 S = {\rm devec}\Big((I\otimes I - A^T\otimes A^T)^{-1}\,{\rm vec}(I)\Big) \cr
}$$
Now choose a factorization (Cholesky) that has the desired form.

Comment: this method computes $S$ explicitly. And we also can compute $S$ by the original definition. Is there any closed-form solution for $R$?